# Linux MCP decompile.sh?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, minecraft

I'm using Ubuntu and I have the following problem, when I want to decompile Minecraft (with decompile.sh) I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print('')?
```

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

The shell script assumes that `python` is Python 2, but on your system it's Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you view the script you will realize it runs one line only, install python2 and edit the script to python2.* (check what python2 you have and replace with * and save and run.